# dlm package in R: What is causing this error: `tsp<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(1, 200, 1))

Tags: r, time-series

I am using `dlm` package in R for performing Kalman filtering for the following simulated data.

```
## Multivariate time-series of dimension 200 and length 3
obsTimeSeries <- cbind(rnorm(200, 1, 2), rnorm(200, 2, 2), rnorm(200, 3, 2))
tseries <- ts(obsTimeSeries, frequency = 1)

kalmanBuild <- function (par) {

    kalmanMod <- dlm(FF = diag(1, 200), GG = diag(1, 200),
                     V = exp(par[1]) * diag(1, 200),
                     W = exp(par[2]) * diag(1, 200),
                     m0 = rep(0, 200), C0 = 1e100 * diag(1, 200))
    kalmanMod
}

kalmanMLE <- dlmMLE(tseries, parm = rep(0, 2), build = kalmanBuild)
kalmanMod <- kalmanBuild(kalmanMLE$par)
kalmanFilt <- dlmFilter (tseries, kalmanMod)
```

The code until `kalmanMod` works fine.  It give an error in `dlmFilter(tseries, kalmanMod)` saying `` `tsp<- ``(`*tmp*`, value = c(1, 200, 1))`.

I tried to look for the location of error.  It seems that the filtering works fine, that is, the means and variances are estimated correctly, until in the very last part when the code assigns `tsp(ans$a) <- ytsp`, the error occurs.

Has anyone else face this problem?  If yes, then what am I doing wrong.

Comment: It might be very possible that I am setting up the time series incorrectly. I am sorry I have limited experience with handling time-series in R.  Basically I am observing a 200x1 vector at 3 time-points.

Comment: I am tempted to say this because setting `tsp(tseries) <- NULL` gives no errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to:

```
obsTimeSeries <- rbind(rnorm(200, 1, 2), rnorm(200, 2, 2), rnorm(200, 3, 2))
```

rather than:

```
obsTimeSeries <- cbind(rnorm(200, 1, 2), rnorm(200, 2, 2), rnorm(200, 3, 2))
```

Your time series was set up to be 3 series at 200 time points. If you change it to rbind you will have a ts with 200 series at 3 time points.